# How to deactivate the flow using workbench API

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, workbench

How to deactivate/delete flow through WorkBench API or Apex? I tried all possible ways. could anyone help out here?

Comment: The config switch on https://cloudtoolkit.co/ can do it. Can you explain the scenario in more detail (why via API/Apex), then we might be able to suggest differently.

Comment: @Girbot The requirement is in the org they have some set of flows. Now they want a separate custom UI with additional description to display all the active flows. if they want to deactivate any flow they can do this with one button click

Comment: This would be something like out of box functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use Workbench to retrieve metadata components and deactivate a flow, Once you retrive download those components in a .zip file and modify the flowDefinition file by specifying a value of 0 in activeversionNumber.

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlowDefinition xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <activeversionNumber>0</activeversionNumber>
</FlowDefinition>
```

Re-zip and then deploy the modified flowDefinition file.
Check more details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000338777&type=1).  For mass delete of flows check steps [mentioned](https://getridbug.com/salesforce/mass-delete-flow-and-flow-versions/).

Use Ben Edwards tool 'https://sfswitch.herokuapp.com' to disable process using toggle.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: the following error I am getting in workbench 
message: You must provide a valid Metadata field for InteractionDefinitionVersion

Comment: Can you share packge.xml, metadata file pls